# WIll Robocopy copy and replace files if they become corrupted?

Tags: windows-10, robocopy

I have Robocopy set up to copy files to a network storage location from folders on a Hard Disk. In the event of some sort of issue with my HDD, where the files become corrupted, will Robocopy copy over the corrupted files to the network location and replace the backed up files, therefore making my entire backup process pointless?

Comment: Well if the corruption is so bad that it cannot read the data from the disk, then no. If it can read the attributes of the file then it'll copy it over as far as I know.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Any suggestions as to how I could handle this issue? To make sure that any corrupted files won't be copied?

Comment: I'm not sure really maybe compare a hash check or checksum against a known good file for each file you are backing up. I'm not certain Robocopy is the tool for that. You might have to build something from scratch and it'd add overhead to the backup process. I'm not sure what type of data each file is, but there may be a way to tell programmatically that file is valid and can be read, etc. and if that is successful to copy it over. There may be a backup software solution that has some of these features built in too but I'm not sure. I never worry about inspecting for file corruption backing up.